# Como enviar un formulario POST desde un controlador con parametros y luego redirigir

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy tratando de usar el webcheckout de payulatam para generar compras desde mi website, el problema es que al webcheckout de payu hay que llegar desde un formulario al cual se le hace submit y redirecciona a la pagina de payu.

El tema es que yo estoy tratando de hacer eso mismo pero desde un controlador. Estube tratando con el nuevo HTTP Client de laravel 8, pero no me redirige hacia la pagina de payu:

```
Http::asForm()->post('https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu/', [
        'amount' => $amount,
        'referenceCode' => $referenceCode,
        'merchantId' => $merchantId,
        'accountId' => $accountId,
        'description' => $description,
        'tax' => $tax,
        'taxReturnBase' => $taxReturnBase,
        'signature' => $signature,
        'currency' => $currency,
        'test' => $test,
        'buyerEmail' => $buyerEmail
    ]);
```

Estuve probando también con curl pero no supe hacerlo. Podrian indicarme como es posible realizar esto?

Comment: Payu tiene su propia [API](http://developers.payulatam.com/es/api/) para hacer esto, lo probastes? Por otro lado, sabes si se esta realizando la peticion con exito?

Comment: `cURL` realiza peticiones entre servidores y sin tomar en cuenta lo que pasa en el navegador; supongo que el cliente `Http` de Laravel funciona igual. Coincido con @JuanRivera en que deberías usar la API.